# Does this DOCTYPE tag make IE9 render a page in compatibilty mode?

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

I just started working on a website, and in IE9 it is rendering in "*IE9 compatibility view*" browser mode.

Is there anything in the following DOCTYPE tag that would force that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The full contents of the `<head>` tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Applications</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Applications" />
<meta name="Description" content="Applications" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui/2009/css/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui/2009/css/standard.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui/2009/css/home.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="ui/2009/css/print.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui/2009/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui/2009/css/ie6.css" /><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/swfobject-2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Can you post your complete head and have you validated your complete HTML source?

Comment: Posted complete head. How do I validate my complete HTML source?

Comment: You can validate your HTML [here](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know is it possible to solve problem by modifying the doctype

But its meta tag should help you:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
```

IE=edge - it says to IE to use highest mode available and chrome=1 - it says to IE6,7,8,9 to use Chrome frame (if it is installed)

Comment: This is what ultimately made the page not kick into compatibility mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to use an (old) XHTML doctype?

If not, use the current one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: So I should replace ``<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`` with ``<!DOCTYPE html>`` ?

Comment: @novicePrgrmr In my opinion, yes.

Comment: Yeah, you should try it. It makes your document a HTML5 document. HTML5 can be considered a superset of XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in the doctype that causes “compatibility mode” (aka “quirks mode”). It is one of the doctypes that triggers “standards mode”. But on IE, there are several things that may put the browser into “compatibility mode”.

Perhaps at the simplest, try visiting any web page on IE 9, pressing F12, selecting “compatibility mode”, then visiting another page. The browser will remain in “compatibility mode” even though the new page has a standards-conforming doctype. That is, manually setting the mode makes it persistent.

There are other possible causes too, see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Answer (score -3):

Sirko - Not everyone in the world has HTML5 / XHTML5 browser capability.  Until it is 100% standardized and is the 'majority' not the 'minority' that use it, XHTML 1.0 (or 2.0) for widespread compatibility is much better.

IE9 is going into compatibility view because IE9 only natively supports XHTML5 and not the older XHTML 1.0 and XHTML 2.0

Check here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/11/01/xhtml-in-ie9.aspx

You can validate your website here:

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

Hope it helps =)

Comment: There's no XHTML on the Web today if you target IE8- (see also http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml). Also, besides new features, one major things standardized by HTML5 is parsing of HTML so that browsers following the spec are _compatible with the Web as we know it_ (specifically not the one the W3C dreamed about with HTML4 and XHTML). So, as far as DOCTYPE and Quirks/Standards Modes are concerned, HTML5 is already supported by 100% of browsers.